# better way to avoid use of ls inside of variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, ls

**not sure about how to correctly title this, please change it if you prefer**

given that my code actually works, I'd like to have a peer review to increase the quality of it.

I have a folder full of .zip files. Theese files are streams of data (identifiable by their stream name) daily offloaded. There could be more than one daily file per stream, so I need to grab the last one in order of time. I can't rely on posix timestamp for this, so files expose timestamp on their name.

Filename example: 
`XX_XXYYZZ_XYZ_05_AB00C901_T001_20170808210052_20170808210631.zip`

- Last two fields are timestamps, and I'm interested in the **second-last**.
- other fields are useless (now)

I've previously stored the stream name (in this case `XYZ_05_AB00C901_T001` in the variable `$stream`

I have this line of code:

`match=$(ls "$streamPath"/*.zip|grep "$stream"|rev|cut -d'_' -f2|rev|sort|tail -1)`

And what it does is to search the given path for files matching the stream, cutting out the timestamp and sorting them. So now that I know what is the last timestamp for this stream, I can `ls` again, this time grepping for `$stream`and `$match` togegher, and I'm done:

`streamFile=$(ls "$streamPath"/.zip|grep "$stream.*$match\|$match.*$stream")`

Question time:

- Is there a better way to achieve my goal ? Probably more than one, I'll prefer one-liner solution, tough.
- ShellChecks advices me that it would be better to use a `for` loop or a `while` cycle instead of `ls`, to be able to handle particular filenames (which I'm not facing ATM, but who knows), but I'm not so sure about it (seems more complicated to me).

Thanks.

O.

Comment: Show the example output for the `ls`, and also the expected output of the command.

Comment: You might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: is that timestamp reflects the real modification time of the file?

Comment: This might help: [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the page suggested by Cyrus I chose to go with this solution:

```
  echo "$file"|grep "$stream"|rev|cut -d'_' -f2|rev|sort|tail -1
done < <(find "$streamPath" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.zip' -print0)
```